# Where can I buy ground coffee in Beijing?

Tags: ground-coffee, coffee-culture

I recently moved to Beijing and now realized coffee is not so popular here as it is in America. There is a Walmart supermarket near to where I live but guess it, there is no ground coffee there.

Where can I buy ground coffee in Beijing?

Comment: Alibaba should have coffee. And, whole bean may be fresher and it is almost as easy.  I would prefer using a blade grounder than getting pre-ground coffee.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use online buying like jd.com, taobao.com.
2. Some coffee house will sell ground coffee.

Comment: Maybe it's better to pinpoint a few locations for a stranger in the second option?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find illy at Walmart but the price is usually much higher than that you may find on Tmall (both ground and beans. Try their app).